# Selenium Library: When I search for an element, it shows me an error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I was using the Selenium library and I wrote this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl")

search_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
search_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "btnK")
```

But I always get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/user_jsd/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    search_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
NameError: name 'By' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the import statements below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```